# Perform arithmetic operations on all "cells" in tab-delimited file

Tags: shell

I have a tab delimited file of n by m (where n is number of rows and m is number of columns).

I want to perform a mathematical operation on values present in the file (say adding 5 to value present in each column and then dividing it by 12).

any one line regex command or a mixture of things .... help

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using awk:

```
gawk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 1) {printf "%f\t", ($i + 5) / 12;} printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: Note: fixed 2 bugs since the initial posting.

Comment: good one, last doubt how to indicate the file name ... in which the operation is to be performed

Comment: you can either append the file name to the command (`gawk ... file.txt`) or pipe the file content into the command (i.e. `cat file.txt|gawk ...`)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{
   # add all numbers on a line
   tot=0
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) tot+=$i

   # print detail
   print "LineNo=" NR "\ttot="tot "\tavg=" tot/12 "data=" $0 
   gTot+=tot
   }
   END {
         print "Number of Lines =" NR "\n" \
                GrandTotal=\t" gTot
       }
   ' yourFile
```

You'll want to work thru this [excellent awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to really understand what is happening.

Comment: hey, Thank you for your comment and suggestion. I have already accepted the answer from soulmerge and I cannot give a vote to ur answer as I need to have 15 points... but awk tutorial suggested by you is worth looking. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

try sed or awk (awk is very good) they were designed to do that

Comment: since others got in first I wont give my own example but would say a few hours spent learning sed and awk (and grep) will save you a lot of hard work in the future; they are 3 utilities that always pay dividends